# How to send keys to a Half Life 1 window?

Tags: c, winapi

I am trying to send the "Up arrow" to a Half Life 1 window using the following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    Sleep(3000);

    // Up arrow
    keybd_event(VK_UP, 0, 0, 0);
    keybd_event(VK_UP, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

But it is not working! does Half Life 1 only allows somehow the key presses to be sent from the actual hardware keyboard?

Comment: @BeyelerStudios But not only to that? I think the cause may be `keybd_event` isn't sending scancode here. `SendInput` may be useful.

Comment: @user it's normal for games to behave this way. You probably need to work out how this program accepts input.

Comment: Did you try whether other applications, e.g. Notepad receive keyboard events this way?

Comment: @Serge Rogatch Yes it works with Notepad and other applications.

Answer (score -2):

The thing is the game will receive your inputs but it doesn't handle the events because it has no instructions to handle the event. I mean it will have keyboard event handling code but they will obviously override your actions.

Comment: I think this was meant to be a comment.